# Hbase node could not be reached from Hbase java api client

Tags: java, hbase, apache-zookeeper

I'm trying to connect to an hbase cluster using the java api.
The api is connecting to the zookeeper after that is trying to connect to a cluster node. But this time fails with this error:

```
INFO ipc.HBaseRPC: Server at <server-name>/<ip>:60020 could not be reached after 1 tries, giving up.
```

The port in the node is open because is default open by the hbase.
I'm using the default settings for hbase.
The node is set as regional server.
I've try using the standalone configuration for hbase and is working the difference is the port that the api is connecting after zookeeper which is not the same.

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps but if your using a standalone how are you connecting to a region server? Shouldn't it be master?  Are you able to connect to the hbase shell on the local machine?

Comment: Solved the issue by using fully qualified domain names (FQDN) in host files and using FQDN of name node as zookeeper quorum host in hbase-site.xml.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I configured the cluser using cloudera Manager.

The solution is: remove the `127.0.0.1` entry from the `/etc/hosts` file.

Comment: Wouldn't expect it to work either.  This is just a "voodoo programming" suggestion ... unless someone has added a **bogus** entry for 127.0.0.1.  (A normal 127.0.0.1 entry uses the name "localhost" ... and that is just fine.)

Answer (score 0):

If you are connecting to a remote HBase cluster - make sure to add **all** of cluster hostnames and ip's to your local hosts file (/etc/hosts on Linux or C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts on Windows), like in the following example:

192.168.150.101 vm01.domain.com

192.168.150.102 vm02.domain.com

192.168.150.103 vm03.domain.com

192.168.150.104 vm04.domain.com

Apparently Zookeper uses hostname instead of ip somewhere when trying to connect to HBase and it can be a problem when connecting remotely with Java.

Hope it helps!